# Do any of zero coefficients become non-zero by increasing $\lambda$ in lasso regression?

Tags: regression, lasso

In lasso regression many coefficients become zero as discussed [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiGk9u1wtrtAhWNxYUKHR9wCmEQFjANegQIGRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FWhy-is-it-that-the-lasso-unlike-ridge-regression-results-in-coefficient-estimates-that-are-exactly-equal-to-zero&usg=AOvVaw1IulRkp-1ztbkW6XqtTWmF)
$$ \min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p}\frac{1}{N}||y-\beta X||_2^2+||\lambda\beta||_1 $$
Columns of $X$ are $\{x_j \}_{j=1}^p$ corresponding to $p$ variables and $y$ is answer variable.
During any iteration, we increase $\lambda$. So some coefficients become zero. When it goes on, is it possible that some zero coefficients that were zero in iteration $i$ become non-zero in iteration $i+1$? If so, why? and if not, dose it have proof?
The only thing I know is when we set $\lambda = \lambda_{max}=\max_{j}|\frac{1}{N}\langle x_j,y\rangle|$ or greater all coefficients become zero and the number of zero coefficients is increasing when $\lambda$ increases.

Comment: A bit related: ["Intuition for nonmonotonicity of coefficient paths in ridge regression"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414088).