# Why does Ridge Regression affect certain coefficients differently?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, ridge-regression

From my understanding, Ridge regression tends to shrink coefficients towards 0 as lambda increases. However, it seems this is not always the case - for features which are more statistically significant, Ridge Regression can increase their coefficient as lambda increases. Why is this? And how does the Ridge penalty cause this?

[image]

Comment: A related question is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414088/ would my answer there answer your question here? *"The ridge path is not a straight line ... Shrinking the parameters in a straight line from the OLS solution to 0, means that the sum of squared error becomes high. Taking a detour allows to shrink the parameters with less reduction of the sum of least squared error."*